# How to change the amount of elements in an array without creating a new one

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

I want to create an array whose number of stored values increases by one every time a button is clicked. So I need a way to change the number of array elements during run-time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Array.resize()` method.

Documentation can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netframework-4.7.2

Array.Resize doesn't resize the array, it creates a new array with the specified size and copies all the elements from the old array to the newly created array and then replaces the old array with the new array however this would be suitable for you based on your question.